# Does mysqli reuse connections within the same request?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a piece of code that opens several redundant connections to the same DB. Basically, the same "connect" method is being called multiple times (tens to hundreds, depending on the data) resulting in multiple identical calls to `new mysqli()`.

So I was wondering - is this really as bad as it sounds, or perhaps PHP/mysqli somehow reuses a single connection in this case?

Comment: You should create one connection and store it in the global var. use it across the project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, creating a new mysqli instance will create a new connection by default.

You could either wrap your mysqli instance into a Singleton pattern (not recommended) or instantiate only one instance and then use Dependency Injection to pass this one instance around.

Comment: I know of various patterns how to do it, but this one was new to me. :) I just wanted to give the code the benefit of doubt before declaring it as bad. :)

Comment: I would assume this relies on the connection being specifically closed before being made available for re-use.  Is this the case?

Comment: Ahahahahahahahaha! no.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's as awfully bad as it sounds.

You should always create just a single connection and then use it throughout the whole script execution. There are many different techniques to achieve so, you can choose one that suits you best.

Note that persistent connection will make it worse, killing your database connection in an instant. The thing about persistent connection is that once opened, it cannot be used by anther process until the timeout expired. Given you are opening multiple connections from the same script, your script is devouring free connections like an ogre. And their number is not infinite.

Comment: Nop, not persistent, at least.